# ¿Como cambiar el color de fondo de pagina con FPDF en php?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Hola y saludos a toda la comunidad. Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en Php que debe generar reportes y hasta los momentos todo bien, pero el usuario dueño de la app requiere un color personalizado del fondo de pagina, ojo no me refiero a las celdas sino a la pagina que genera el metodo `Addpage()`.

He buscado en internet y en la documentacion de FPDF y hasta los momentos no he conseguido algo que funcione o refiera al tema. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco

Comment: Dudo mucho que haya un método para pintar toda la pagina, imagina imprimir eso. Lo que puedes hacer es un rectángulo que rellene toda la pagina y cambiarle el color.

Comment: Como lo dice @DevMind imagina si intenta imprimir ese reporte, no conosco mucho de fpdf, pero puedes utilizar dompdf, con esta libreria te da la opcion de hacer lo que quieras en el archivo que vallas a generar

Comment: Podrías intentar quizá crear una imagen con el color de fondo que quieres y usarla como fondo de la página. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20886692/5587982). De todos modos, es un requerimiento algo extraño, por lo que ya te comentó @DevMind.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario. Si lo probare y revisare DomPdf, aunque estoy usando Fpdf no porque sea un experto con esa libreria, sino que llevo muchas partes de la aplicacion y el reporte muy adelantada. Bueno la idea de poner un color de fondo a la pagina es probar de ser posible  ya que trabajando en la app me di cuenta que para una imagen que estoy manipulando podria ser necesario que esta ocupe una pagina sola completa. Entonces me gustaria cambiar el color de fondo para mejorar el diseño del reporte final.